# Как правильно написать navbar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid, display

я всегда делал navbar через display: flex, но хочу попробовать через grid. как написать правильно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<p id='nav' style='display: grid; grid-auto-flow: column;'><b>это</b><b>nav</b><b>bar</b></p>` всё пожалуй.